# before waiting a response from other script, echo something on screen in php

Tags: php, request

I have a structure like:

```
   echo 'something' on x.php;

   x.php -> Requests to y.php;
   while(x.php -> waiting Response from y.php)
      do something;
```

but it did not work, because server is locked onRequest and after getting response print all 
of 'something' on the screen.

Note: It is not like 'loading..' structure that i want, it's completely different.

Edit:
      The Request code part is like (does not actual code):

```
    while(5){
        echo 'hey hey';
    }

    $whatIWant = 'wanted string';
    $myTopicString = 'topic34593495';
    while(strlen($myTopicString)>2){
         $url = 'y.php/'.$myString;
         $r = request($url);
         $response = response($r);
         if(strpos($response,$whatIWant))
             break;
         $myTopicString -= 1;
    }
```

what i want is printing 'hey hey' string on the screen and see it before the request.

Comment: What kind of requests are you talking about. Can you show some code?

Comment: That doesn't clarify it at all. What kind of request is being made where, on server side or on client side? Ideally show some code.

Comment: Why don't you show us actual code? That would show us better what you're trying to do. The 5 in `while(5)` will always evaluate to true, so this script would keep echoing hey hey and never even reach the rest of the code.

Comment: I know, this is just simulating, actual code is so complicated to understand, that's why i don't show. I just want to see 'hey hey' on the screen before the request starts

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to do something AJAX was built for.
So please check out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: Doing something while waiting for another thread to finish is almost the definition of "asynchronous" which is what the first letter of AJAX is standing for. Echoing something is client side thus javascript which is what the middle two characters of AJAX stand for. Still I don't KNOW, I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is heavy and needs some severe loading-time you should consider AJAX. So first show the main screen elements. After that you retrieve data using JavaScript.